# I want to pass data to the Basket page but the screen is blank, it shows nothing

Tags: flutter, dart

I created a Checkbox List and I want the selected/checked item to be passed to the Basket page where you will be able to see what you have chosen. when I click the basket icon to view the selected items I just get an empty screen.

Your contribution would be highly appreciated.

The Main Widget

```
import 'package:cart_app/Basket.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(),
      home: MyHomePage(),
      routes: {
        Basket.routeName: (context) => Basket(),
      },
    );
  }
}
```

The Product List Page

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Map<String, bool> values = {
    "GIN COCKTAILS \nClover Club \t  R65": false,
    "Beers & Ciders \nHeineken NRB \t R29": false,
    "Vodka \nCiroc \t R35": false,
    "Vodka \nCruz Vodka \t R30": false,
    "COGNAC \nHennesy \t R40": false,
    "Tequilla \nEl Jimador \t R30": false,
    "Non-Alcoholic \nSoft-Drink \t R20": false,
    "WHISK[E]Y \nJohnie Walker Red \t R25": false,
  };

  var toggle = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("The Wing Republic"),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.of(context)
                  .pushNamed(Basket.routeName, arguments: values);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: values.keys.map((String key) {
          return CheckboxListTile(
            title: Text(key),
            subtitle: Text(""),
            isThreeLine: false,
            value: values[key],
            onChanged: (bool value) {
              setState(() {
                values[key] = value;
              });
            },
          );
        }).toList(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The Basket Page. This is the page where I want to dispalay the data from the product list page

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Basket extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/Basket';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final data = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as Map<String, bool>;
    return Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scaffold() in your Basket class is empty. This will result in an black or "empty" screen. Add some widgets to display the values passed to the Basket Widget:

```
Scaffold(
   body: Container (
      child: Column(
         children: Widgets[
            // Text Widgets with the passed values
            Text(data["key"]),
             Text(data["key"])
         ]
      )
   )
)
```

Comment: I am new to flutter so I was wondering what widgets should i use to display the selected items from the list, in the Basket page?

Comment: I updated my response. I would suggest to started with a basic Text widget. The Flutter documentation also is extremely helpful with finding widgets to display information.